# BluetoothSocket connect failed

Tags: android, bluetooth

My demo is just determined to build a connection between two phones.But when my client tries to call `bluetoothSocket.connect()` it throws an IOException with the message `no route to host`.I have tried many approaches but it doesn't work.

Here is my code about AcceptThread and ConnectThread (deleted some unrelated code to make it more concise)

```
class AcceptThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
    BluetoothServerSocket tmp;

    public AcceptThread() {

        Method listenMethod = null;
        try {
            listenMethod = bluetoothAdapter.getClass().getMethod("listenUsingRfcommOn",new Class[]{int.class});
        } 
        try {
            tmp = ( BluetoothServerSocket) listenMethod.invoke(bluetoothAdapter, new Object[]{30});
        } 
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        while (isAcceptRun) {
            try {
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "run: AB "+e);
                break;
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    mmServerSocket.close();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {

        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;
        Method m = null;
        try {
            m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
        } 
        try {
            tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, Integer.valueOf(30));
        } 
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [BluetoothChat](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat) example from Google, the BluetoothSocket is constructed by:

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
            UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

if (secure) {
   tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
            MY_UUID_SECURE);
} else {
   tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
            MY_UUID_INSECURE);
}
```

Comment: Strangely,if I use `listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord()` to get the BluetoothServerSocket,the return value is null.And I think my method is right too.Thanks,anyway.